# DevCon.exe installation

Tags: windows-10, device-manager, sdk, devcon

I've got a problem during installation devcon. Devcon is a MSC software to manage with peripherials moare accurate.
I know that devcon is a part of WDK, but i want to install just devcon without other tools. To launch devcon.exe should i add devcon's path to enviromental variable, or should i install some third part software (i've heard about Visual Studio and Windows SDK).
Please give me some kind of instruction to deal with that problem.
My Widnows Platform:
Windows 10
1809 version